# Securing a location in firebase database for one or more users to write to

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm building a new application using firebase authentication and realtime database. I understand how to secure a location in the database so that only a specific authenticated user can write to it, as per the documentation:

```
{
"rules": {
  "users": {
    "$user_id": {
      // grants write access to the owner of this user account
      // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
      ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
    }
  }
}
```

}

I want to secure a location for one or more users. I'm not sure whether that is possible and if so, how would I structure the data. The data is a list of shopping items that one or more users can update, while all other users can view the shopping items. All users are authenticated, but one or more of them is designated as the shopper, so they are allowed to add and remove items.

Thanks

Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone stumbles across this, a member of the firebase forum was able to answer the question and I ended up with the following database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      "$udser_id": {
        ".write": "$user_id === aith.uid"
      }
    },
    "shops": {
      "$shopID": {
        "items": {
          ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": "data.parent().child('shoppers').child(auth.uid).exists()"
        },
        "shoppers": {
          ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('scheduler').val() == true || data.child(auth.uid).exists()"
        },
        "boxes": {
          ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": "auth != null"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This was based on an article here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/group-security-in-firebase-database.html